# Hashtag preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a web app which is creating and linking to `#hashtags` and I have noticed that if someone creates a `#hashtag` of `#JB22` that the following code breaks.

Is there away in the regex I can allow numbers at the end of a `#hashtag`

```
$users = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"user\" class=\"userHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>$2|$3</_link> ", $start);
$tags = preg_replace("~(<var data-type=\"tag\" class=\"tagHighlight\" id=\"(.*?)\">)#(.*?)(</var>)~", "<_link>tag://$3|#$3</_link> ", $users);
$last = preg_replace("~(^|\\s)#(\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)~", " <_link>tag://$2|#$2</_link> ", $tags);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this `[a-zA-Z_]+` with `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+` or if you want the numbers only at the end of the pattern you can use `([a-zA-Z_]+?[a-zA-Z_0-9]+?)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add the 0-9 block to your regex to search for numbers as well:

```
$last = preg_replace("~(^|\\s)#(\\w*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\w*)~", " <_link>tag://$2|#$2</_link> ", $tags);
```

Note: You should be using some sort of DOM Document parser to HTML/XML mark up.

Comment: Samuel normally I'd recommend DOM Document, but if the processing is simple and predictable enough it doesn't make sense -- DOM Documents are slow beasts.